# How to reduce a given number in a two digit number in java

Tags: java, string

This is the problem I'm trying to solve. Given a number like 6928:

- difference between 6 and 9 is 3
- difference between 9 and 2 is 7
- difference between 2 and 8 is 6

So, the reduced form is 376. Since this is not a two-digit number, we repeat the process:

- difference between 3 and 7 is 4
- difference between 7 and 6 is 1

The result is 41, which is a two digit number, and the solution.

This is my attempt:

```
public int twodigit(int inp){
  String val = "";
  String s = Integer.toString(inp);
  while(s.length() > 2) {
    s = strfind(s);
  }
  int n = integer.parseInt(s);
  return n; 
}

public String strfind(String s) {
  int len = s.length();
  String mynew = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    char a = s.charAt(i);
    char b = s.charAt(i+1);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
    int dif = Math.abs(x-y);
    String ad = Integer.toString(diff);
    mynew = mynew + ad;
  }
  s = mynew;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Recommend more better solution for this

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what errors are you getting? Or how does the output differ from what you want?

Comment: this code is working, but i am looking for a more better solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523416/how-to-reduce-a-given-number-in-a-two-digit-number-in-java#comment90015934_51523416):

> this code is working, but i am looking for a more better solution for this

Here is an implementation that use *recursion* instead of `String` manipulation.

As [Pshemo said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523416/how-to-reduce-a-given-number-in-a-two-digit-number-in-java#comment90016125_51523416):

> Try to avoid converting between integer and string. Purely integer based solution is not that hard to create and has a chance to be faster. To get last digits of number with modulo 10 (like `number%10`), to remove last digit divide by 10 (`number = number / 10;`).

---

```
public static int twodigit(int value) {
    while (value > 99)
        value = reduce(value);
    return value;
}
private static int reduce(int value) {
    return (value <= 9 ? 0 : reduce(value / 10) * 10 + Math.abs(value / 10 % 10 - value % 10));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(twodigit(6928));
```

*Output*

```
41
```

---

**UPDATE** Explanation of `reduce()` method, i.e. the following statement:

```
return (value <= 9 ? 0 : reduce(value / 10) * 10 + Math.abs(value / 10 % 10 - value % 10));
```

which can also be written as:

```
if (value <= 9)
    return 0;
int lastDigit = value % 10;
int higherDigits = value / 10;
int secondLastDigit = higherDigits % 10;
int difference = Math.abs(secondLastDigit - lastDigit);
int higherReduced = reduce(higherDigits); // recursive call
int result = higherReduced * 10 + difference;
return result;
```

Calculating modulus 10 will return the last digit of a number, e.g. `6928 % 10` is `8`.

With integer math, dividing by 10 will discard the last digit, e.g. `6928 / 10` is `692`.

First call `reduce(6928)`:

```
lastDigit       = 6928 % 10       = 8
higherDigits    = 6928 / 10       = 692
secondLastDigit = 692 % 10        = 2
difference      = Math.abs(2 - 8) = 6
higherReduced   = reduce(692)     = 37   // see next
result          = 37 * 10 + 6     = 376
```

Recursive call `reduce(692)`:

```
lastDigit       = 692 % 10        = 2
higherDigits    = 692 / 10        = 69
secondLastDigit = 69 % 10         = 9
difference      = Math.abs(9 - 2) = 7
higherReduced   = reduce(69)      = 3    // see next
result          = 3 * 10 + 7      = 37
```

Recursive call `reduce(69)`:

```
lastDigit       = 69 % 10         = 9
higherDigits    = 69 / 10         = 6
secondLastDigit = 6 % 10          = 6
difference      = Math.abs(6 - 9) = 3
higherReduced   = reduce(6)       = 0    // see next
result          = 0 * 10 + 3      = 3
```

Recursive call `reduce(6)`:

```
if (value <= 9)
    return 0;
```

Comment: Could you explain this line theoretically, that how it will work -->
    `return (value <= 9 ? 0 : reduce(value / 10) * 10 + Math.abs(value / 10 % 10 - value % 10));`  @Andreas